# Optimize filter and sort of rich:dataTable

Tags: ajax, jsf, datatable, richfaces

I've created a RichFaces filtered data table, using the [Exadel demo](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/filteringFeature.jsf?c=filtering&tab=usage) as a model. While the functionality of my table seems fine, the performance is an issue. When I hook up Firebug's Net Panel, I can see that the response I'm getting to the AJAX filter request is much bigger than what the Exadel demo gets, and I'm confused why.

First, if I don't have `<a4j:region renderRegionOnly="true">` somewhere around the table, then the response is the full text of the page, not just the table. The Exadel demo doesn't seem to require setting up this region.

Second, even when I set up a region, and the AJAX response is limited to the table data, italso includes the `<head>` section of the HTML page, with all its link references and script definitions. That doesn't happen with the Exadel demo. Its AJAX response to a filtering request has an empty `<head>` section. Is there a configuration that controls this behavior?

Any suggestions towards optimizing this process would be greatly appreciated. Right now I'm getting a 225K response back for two rows and nine columns of data, which really only consist of maybe 2K of actual data.

I'm using JSF 1.2 and RichFaces 3.3.1 on JBoss 4.2.3.

Comment: Can you post the code of your page and the backing bean behind it?